# MySQL Limit Event Happens On When

Tags: mysql

I got one question over here towards MySQL Limit.

- let's say i got one table with 100 rows
- then after i done query operation (SELECT, WHERE, etc etc)
- then i limit the size with LIMIT(10)

in this case the MySQL is retrieving the 100 rows records first then only cut to size 10 **OR** count the result size until 10 then stop retrieving the remaining already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think about this logically, and maybe the answer will become evident.  Imagine you are using the following query:

```
SELECT someCol
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY someCol
LIMIT 10
```

It should be intuitive that MySQL has to know the ordinal position of every record in the result set in order to be able to guarantee that the 10 records returned are in fact the first 10 records of what the entire result set would be.

If MySQL were to just take the first 10 records which it hit during the scan, then in general it could not guarantee that the records returned respect the ordering you specified.